# Where to find/create .git/config file for local configuration for project?

Tags: git, github

I want to know how I can create/find a .git/config file for my project, as windows does not allow me to put the "/". Also, is this a file or is it a folder?

Is there a difference between .gitconfig and .git/config?

Comment: `/` is the unix pathname separator; on windows it's `\`.  The config file is `config` in the `.git` directory aka `.git` folder.  It should have been created by `git init`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is difference between `.gitconfig` and `.git/config`.

`.git/config` will have the configuration details of your repository. But `.gitconfig` will have your user details and the configuration you set for git like `user.name`, `user.email`, default editor, color setting, etc.

In Windows, you will find the `.gitconfig` file in `C:\Users\user_name`.

`.git/config` file can be located under `<git_repository>/.git/` (`.git/config` gets created once you run `git init` command or you clone an initialized repository).

Answer (score 8):

`.gitconfig` is a global configuration file that resides in your HOMEDIR.

`.git` is your special directory in any git repo that makes it a 'repo'.

Inside .git is a file called `config` that applies all the configurations mentioned in it to that particular repository only.

You can add configurations to either .gitconfig/.git/config using the `git config` command.

Eg:
`git config user.name "Jane Doe"` adds a user.name entry in your current repository's .git/config file

`git config --global user.email "jane.doe@example.com"` adds a user.email entry in your users .gitconfig file, and it will be applicable to all repos under that users.
(Note use of --global)

Using mysysgit has a lot of benefits. Cygwin is also a good option!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

.gitconfig holds all your git configuration for your machine. On each repository, there is a .git folder, and inside it, you can find a config file, which holds information for this particular repo.

I recommend, under Windows, to use msysgit, a improved cmd line tool to work with Git.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Git stores configuration options in three separate files, which lets you scope options to individual repositories, users, or the entire system:

- **repo/.git/config – Repository-specific settings**
- **~/.gitconfig – User-specific settings**

  This is where options set with the --global flag are stored.

  git config --global user.name "Love"

  git config --global user.email love@example.com
- **$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig – System-wide settings.**